# Scrape tables of unequal lengths and fill with NA when html node is not present in R

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, nodes, rvest

I would like to scrape some tables off the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/). The original website deletes their data after a period of time so I'm scraping off wayback for reproducibility. The pages have two types of tables of different lengths. I would like to scrape all of them and put them in the same data frame. The first type of table only has four columns while the second has 7. For simplicity, I'll only use two of the 400 links

I would like for the table to show NA for nodes that are not present on that page. So in the first photo, it would show NA for the columns adultWorldChamp, M1WorldChamp, and M2WorldChamp. I have an idea of what to do, but it doesn't quite work right.

Any guidance?

```
library(rvest); library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium); library(netstat)

links2 = c("https://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053146",
"https://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053225")

# Start server
remote_driver = rsDriver(browser = 'firefox',
                         verbose = F,
                         port = free_port())
rd = remote_driver$client
rd$open()
rd$navigate('https://web.archive.org/web/20220000000000*/https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053147&')
rd$maxWindowSize()

## create empty vector  
all.ranks = data.frame()

# Start scraping! ----
for (i in 1:2){
  rd$navigate(links2[i])
  Sys.sleep(10)
  date = rd$findElement(using = 'css', '.captures-range-info a:last-of-type')
  date$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(10)
  
  # Get pg source to read html data
  html = read_html(rd$getPageSource()[[1]])
  
# define function to get basic info
getBasicInfo <- function(basic){

  # create a df with basic info
  df <- data.frame(rank = parseMatch(basic,'.prioriry-number', TRUE),
                   name = parseMatch(basic,'.competitor-name', TRUE),
                   gym = parseMatch(basic,'th+ td', FALSE),
                   grand_slam_pts = parseMatch(basic,'td:nth-child(3)', FALSE),
                   overall_pts = parseMatch(basic,'.text-center+ td', FALSE)) 

  return(df)
}

basic_info <- map_df(html, getBasicInfo)

# grab worlds info
worlds <- html %>% 
  html_elements(css = "td:nth-child(4) , td:nth-child(5) , td:nth-child(3)") %>% 
  html_text2()

# add worlds info to basic info 
all_info <- basic_info %>%
  mutate('AdultWorldChamp' = worlds[1],
         'M1WorldChamp' = worlds[2],
         'M2WorldChamp' = worlds[3])

  
all.ranks = rbind(all.ranks, all_info)
}
```

[image: Table with only four columns]

[image: table with 7 columns]

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

df_1 <- "https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053147&" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(1) %>% 
  set_colnames(c("name", "team", "grand_slam", "overall")) %>% 
  na.omit()
  
df_2 <- "https://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1869/categories/2053225" %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  getElement(1) %>% 
  set_colnames(c("name", "team", "adult", "m1", "m2", "grand_slam", "overall")) %>% 
  na.omit()

# A tibble: 55 × 7
   name                                      team          grand_slam overall adult m1    m2   
   <chr>                                     <chr>              <int>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 "1\nMark Luebking"                        CheckMat             108     111 NA    NA    NA   
 2 "2\nLio Alexander Duarte"                 Brazilian To…         36      49 NA    NA    NA   
 3 "3\nOscar Alberto Borrego"                Patrick Alme…         12      18 NA    NA    NA   
 4 "4\nLuis Alberto Ogaz Varela"             Soul Fighter…          0     108 NA    NA    NA   
 5 "5\nGeorge Christopher A. Baron"          Aloisio Silv…          0       4 NA    NA    NA   
 6 "6\nOmar Eduardo Alfaro Solis"            LEAD BJJ               0       0 NA    NA    NA   
 7 "7\nLucas John Wagner"                    Alliance               0       0 NA    NA    NA   
 8 "8\nFrancisco J. O'Ryan Lesser"           Cohab Chile            0       0 NA    NA    NA   
 9 "9\nBryan Nguyen"                         Logic                  0       0 NA    NA    NA   
10 "1\nJoe Hisataka Frederick Chiaki Scovel" SF Empire Ji…        189     189 No    No    Yes  
11 "2\nDiego de Araujo Saraiva"              Nova União           224     809 No    No    No   
12 "3\nDavid Dimopoulos Said"                Alliance Int…        191     151 No    No    No   
13 "4\nOsvaldo Augusto Honorio Moizinho"     Ares BJJ              57     137 No    No    No   
14 "5\nDiego Asenjo de Paula"                Fabin Rosa B…         47     269 No    No    No   
15 "6\nJohnson Clay Telford"                 G13 BJJ USA           36     225 No    No    No   
# … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. Sorry for not specifying this earlier, but the original website deletes their data after a period of time. So we copied all the links and saved them on the [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/). There are over 400 links I need to scrape, but because that was way too many to include in this post, I subset it so there are only two links. I've updated my post to reflect this.